# Importing .csv data to matrix

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, textscan

I have a `.csv` file with the following 'configuration'

```
'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string'
'string', 'string', 21, 89, 67
'string', 'string', 45, 12, -16
'string', 'string', 78, 56, 45
'string', 'string', 23, 65, 90
'string', 'string', 43, 34, 75
```

I would like to ignore the first two columns and the first row, and import the numbers to a matrix.

I have tried using `textscan`, but without luck. Any experts? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html):

```
x = importdata('filename.csv');
```

This gives an `x` struct with `data` and `textdata` fields:

```
>> x
x = 
        data: [5x3 double]
    textdata: {6x5 cell}
```

To get only the numeric values, use

```
x_numeric = x.data;
```

In your example, this gives

```
x_numeric =
    21    89    67
    45    12   -16
    78    56    45
    23    65    90
    43    34    75
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `dlmread`. You can specify the row and column to start the import.

```
data = dlmread('test.txt',',',1,2)

data =

    21    89    67
    45    12   -16
    78    56    45
    23    65    90
    43    34    75
```

Comment: This looks simpler than with `importdata`

Comment: Thanks. However, yours might be more flexible.